# RegEx LastName, FirstName to FirstName, LastName

Tags: c#, .net

I need 2 Regexs, one where the input is:

```
LastName, FirstName
```

and result should be

```
FirstName, LastName
```

The second Regex should just give me the FirstName

Let me know if you think I need to worry about Jr, Sr, II, etc. If so, probably need more sophisticated Regex.

Comment: Show us your current RegEx, please.

Comment: Using this ^(?<field1>[^,]+),(?<field2>[^,]+)$ for pattern. And using $2, $1 for reverse the order. btw, I am using Nintex Workflow for SharePoint (Regular Expression Builder, which is .net based)

Comment: You may also have to worry about the fact that many people incorrectly write ”Downey Jr., Robert”; it should be ”Downey, Robert Jr.”

Answer (score 7):

Use `String.Split(",")` and reverse the resulting array.

For more sophisticated name-parsing code, look here: 
http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/a57fa506-0afe-4b60-8033-3589eb776315.aspx

Comment: Agreed, and for the second request just return String.Split(",")[0].

Comment: This won't handle Jr/Sr etc if there's a comma.

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = "LastName, FirstName";
var result = string.Join(",", input.Split(',').Reverse());
```

For correct whitespace:

```
var input = "LastName, FirstName";
var result = string.Join(", ", input.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).Reverse());
```

Comment: not sure why nintex wont take this code. howerver, i m Using this ^(?<field1>[^,]+),(?<field2>[^,]+)$ for pattern. And using $2, $1 for reverse the order. btw, I am using Nintex Workflow for SharePoint (Regular Expression Builder, which is .net based). this works but now the firstname has a leading space.